# Are "prompt engineering" and "prompt design" used as synonymous?

Tags: natural-language-processing, terminology, chat-bots, chatgpt

Are "prompt engineering" and "prompt design" used as synonymous / equivalent terms on the day to day communications (not research papers) in Artificial Intelligence community ? Do you simply say "prompt"?

---

I'm "following" questions about ChatGPT. I think that there are too many questions and online content in general that are not making the most appropriate use of terms like

- ChatGPT
- prompt engineering
- prompt design

This makes hard to find helpful content.

#### ChatGPT

*ChatGPT* has being used as a common name like calling a code library "chatgpt" on questions about the OpenAI API, mostly of them specifically about the text completions end-point, some related to packages or libraries that use this end-point. Regarding this term, IMHO, it's clear that it's too early to consider that *ChatGPT* is a common name and people should be encouraged to avoid to use it this way in order to make their post clear about what they are talking about.

#### Prompt Engineering

So far I have read stuff that I was able to find without investing too much time like

- Wikipedia article [prompt engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prompt_engineering) that presents *prompt engineering* as something very broad.
- [Best practices for prompt engineering with OpenAI API](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6654000-best-practices-for-prompt-engineering-with-openai-api) that focus on **writing prompts**.

As an engineer, I like what I understood about what is *prompt engineering* from the Wikipedia article, not the second as it looks to me that trivializes the term.

Some questions, including here, apparently use *prompt engineering* to refer to the *writing prompts*. While might not be wrong to use this term, it looks to me to be way too broad for such specific task.

Related:

The following answers use the term "prompt engineering" but they look to focus on *writing prompts*:

- [Answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/39020/42632) to [What causes ChatGPT to generate responses that refer to itself as a bot or LM?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38361/42632) (from this site)
- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75418423/1595451) to [How to avoid word limit in ChatGPT in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75349226/1595451) (from Stack Overflow)

#### Prompt design

As well that I have done in relation to *prompt engineering*, so far I have read stuff  like the OpenAI API documentation, i.e. [Prompt design](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/completion/prompt-design) that focus on *writing prompts*.

Comment: From my experience from a research standpoint, we describe "prompt engineering" as "the process of exploiting the LLMs knowledge by providing domain-specific keywords in the input text, in order to achieve better performance". It is the same as using Google search: let's say when I search for `How to do multiplications in Python`, I have have (possibly) better answers by using `How to do multiplications in Python site:stackoverflow.com`, which only searches answers on SO.